# how to add Audio track to a Video mp4 file android?

Tags: android, media, audiotrack

I wanted to add audio to a mp4 file,that video doesn't have any audio ,will be added by user selected audio ,How can i achive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your MP4 has been encoded by h.264 , you can easily use [MP4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser).

```
try {
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(baseDir + "/video.h264"));
AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl( baseDir + "/aac_sample.aac" ));

Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.addTrack(h264Track);
movie.addTrack(aacTrack);
Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(baseDir +"/output.mp4")).getChannel();
mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
fc.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I did this by using a media mixer

Comment: cool, but I have never heard of media mixer library, could you send me the link? Thanks

Comment: sorry not media mixer ,it was media muxer android 4.3 api
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html

Comment: Yup, it is for 4.3 and up but mp4parser dose not have this limitation. Good luck

Comment: @rKrishna Would you be kind enough to let us know how you did it using media muxer?